# Question Using law of total probability

Tags: probability

> in a box there 4 coins were $i=\{1,2,3,4\}$.
>   
>   The probability of tail for each coin is: $p_1=0,p_2=0.25,p_3=0.5,p_4=0.75$.
>   
>  a coin is randomly chosen and is thrown over and over until tail appears, what is the probability that there were exactly 3 throws?

I thought that answer will be p(3 throws)$=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.25^3\cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.5^3\cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.75^3$
but the answer is $\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1^2\cdot 0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.75^2\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.5^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.25^2\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ why is that?

Comment: If you flip die $i=2$ to get a tail on the third flip it is probability $(0.75)^2(0.25)$.  You have to account for getting two heads then a tail.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is condition on the coin that was chosen:  let $C \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ be the number of the coin that was chosen.  Then let $X$ represent the number of coin tosses needed to obtain the first tail.  We then want the unconditional probability $$\Pr[X = 3].$$  Conditioning on the outcome of $C$, and noting that the chance of choosing any particular coin is uniform and equal to $1/4$, we have $$\Pr[X = 3] = \sum_{i=1}^4 \Pr[X = 3 \mid C = i]\Pr[C = i] = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 \Pr[X = 3 \mid C = 1].$$  Now, what is the conditional probability in each case?  We note that this follows a geometric distribution:  in order for $X = 3$, we **must** observe the sequence $H, H, T$; any other sequence would not correspond to having flipped exactly three coin tosses to observe the first tail.  Thus the probability of this occurring is $$\Pr[X = 3 \mid C = i] = (1-p_i)^2 p_i.$$  The rest is simply substitution and computation.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the correct answer is:

$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1^2\cdot 0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.75^2\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.5^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0.25^2\cdot \frac{3}{4}$$

It differs at the last fraction.

Now your question:

- You must calculate the probability that there are exactly two heads and then a tail. So in the case of a fair coin, it is $\frac{1}{2}^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$.
- Is the first coin *or* the second *or* the third *or* the fourth, so you should add, not multiply.